# How to pass the value of useState to BackHandler.addEventListener

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Hooks and when I create an event listener for android back press handler, the state inside the callback function handler is empty!

In class components it works fine!

```
'use strict';

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import TextInput from '../../../../components/TextInput';

export default function Foo() {
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      handleValidateClose
    );
    return () => handler.remove();
  }, []);

  const handleValidateClose = () => {
    /* Here is empty */
    console.log(comment);
  };

  return <TextInput onChangeText={setComment} value={comment} />;
}
```

The value should be the useState changed

Answer (score 17):

`handleValidateClose` should be on your dependency array.

You can use your function outside the `useEffect` but should use with `useCallback`.

```js
 const handleValidateClose = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(comment);
    return true;
  }, [comment]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      handleValidateClose,
    );

    return () => handler.remove();
  }, [handleValidateClose]);
```

You can also move the definition to inside `useEffect`, and add a comment as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const handleValidateClose = () => {
      console.log(comment);
      return true;
    };

    const handler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      handleValidateClose,
    );

    return () => handler.remove();
  }, [comment]);
```

To clean things up, create a `useBackHandler`.

```js
export default function useBackHandler(handler) {
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler);

    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handler);
    };
  });
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
const handleValidateClose = () => {
    console.log(comment);
    return true;
  };

  useBackHandler(handleValidateClose);
```

Please config your project to use the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks). That's a [common pitfalls](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/react-hooks-pitfalls) that the plugin would help you with.

Comment: can you explain why it should be in dependency arrays?

Comment: and in my case, i add `comment` as dependency arrays as well, and now it works